# "InvalidArgumentException: Field taxonomy_vocabulary_15 is unknown"

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am trying to publish a *Related_article_link* node, but I get the following exception error.

> InvalidArgumentException: Field taxonomy_vocabulary_15 is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 587 of /mnt/www/html/pllfahcvvibjg/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).

I tried running update.php, `drush cr`, and `drush updb`, but I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly you lost a taxonomy term and there is a content piece in that page that is looking for the term. Taxonomies are not saved in configuration so If you updated your db or changed the environment and you haven't created that term you will get an error.